# How to handle Null in LINQ Subquery?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, null

I've got a subquery that returns the most recent value from a child table. In some cases the subquery returns nothing.  The query below fails at runtime because the inferred type of MemberPrice is decimal and is not nullable.

Simplified query:

```
Dim q = From s In dc.STOCKs _
        Select s.ID, MemberPrice = _
          (From mp In dc.STOCKPRICEs Where mp.NUMBER = s.NUMBER _
          Order By dc.date Descending _
          Select mp.PRICE).FirstOrDefault
```

In SQL, the subquery would contain Top (1) and would return Null when empty. How can I handle this in LINQ? Is there a way to make MemberPrice nullable or default the value to zero if not found (or a more elegant solution)?

Many thanks, Stuart

Comment: Can you define what you mean by fail?  FirstOrDefault should return Nothing if the subquery is empty and hence the MemberPrice should be 0 in that case.

Comment: I get a System.InvalidOperationException {"The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type."}.  I was also expecting it to return 0 if null, so I must be missing something.

Comment: What is the type of mp.PRICE?

Comment: @Stuar, Did you get the solution? Because I have the same problem.

Comment: @Vikas, Yes Roberts answer below is the solution.  Casting to a nullable type solves a whole class of problems I've been having.

Comment: For further clarification, the `FirstOrDefault` is converting the result from a sequence of `Decimal` to a single `Decimal?`. That is the source of the null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stuart,

I changed my Price field in the database to not allow nulls, and I got the same errror you did:

```
"Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'int'".
```

As you pointed out, when Price is set to not allow nulls in the database, the null coalescing operator no longer works because it is expecting to see a nullable type decimal:

```
decimal?
```

If I remove the null coalescing operator and run the test case that doesn't contain a price, I get:

```
"The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type.."
```

Here is the code that works.  I cast the subquery result to decimal? before applying the null coalescing operator.

```
public class Class1
{

    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    public decimal test(int stockID)
    {

        var q = from s in dc.Stocks
                where s.StockID == stockID
                select new
                {
                    StockID = s.StockID,
                    memberPrice = ((decimal?)(from mp in dc.StockPrices
                                   where mp.StockID == s.StockID
                                   select mp.Price).FirstOrDefault()) ?? 0
                };

        return q.FirstOrDefault().memberPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Robert, thank you very much for going above and beyond to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Stuart, try this:

```
Dim q = From s In dc.STOCKs _
    Select s.ID, MemberPrice = _
      if((From mp In dc.STOCKPRICEs Where mp.NUMBER = s.NUMBER _
      Order By dc.date Descending _
      Select mp.PRICE).FirstOrDefault),0)
```

The null coalescing operator will coerce the null value to zero for MemberPrice.

Comment: The null coalescing operator ?? doesn't exist in vb.net

Comment: Yes it does: The If function. As in If(possibleNullValue, valueIfNull)

Comment: @Robert, I editted the code sample to use VB.Net's version of the coalescing operator.

Comment: I get the following compiler error: "First operand in a binary 'If' expression must be nullable or a reference type."

Comment: I'm getting the same compiler error because MemberPrice is inferred to be a value type (decimal).

Answer (score 0):

Does the DefaultIfEmpty extension method do what you're looking for?

Comment: I've used it for flat outer joins but couldn't work out how to get around assigning nothing to the mp.Price decimal value type. Do you have any ideas on syntax I might try?

Answer (score 0):

Stuart,

This is how I got it to work on my machine.  I apologize for it being in c#; it's been too long since I've used VB.

Note the use of the "new" operator in the "select" statement, and the use of the null coalescing operator after the FirstOrDefault().

```
public class Class1
{

    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    public decimal MemberPrice(int stockID)
    {

        var q = from s in dc.Stocks
                where s.StockID == stockID
                select new
                {
                    StockID = s.StockID,
                    memberPrice = (from mp in dc.StockPrices
                                   where mp.StockID == s.StockID
                                   select mp.Price).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0
                };

        return q.FirstOrDefault().memberPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same compiler error with this code in C# because memberPrice is inferred as a decimal (vs Nullable<decimal>). The error is "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'int'".  What is the type of Price on your machine?

Comment: The type of Price on my machine is Decimal(18,0) Allow Nulls.